# After login I only get a terminal window

Tags: auto-login

First of, let me tell you I'm a n00b at ubuntu. I have updated my Ubuntu mediacenter to a later version of ubuntu, currently at 12.04. I'm working through a lot of updates to get to the latest. But since my first update I got the new login screen (lightdm?) and my autologin wasen't working anymore. So I Googled how I could make lightdm autologin. I've managed this by making my /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf look as follows:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=unity-greeter
user-session=ubuntu
autologin-user=my_user
autologin-userutologin-user=-timeout=0
```

Which seemed to work... But now that it automatically logs in, I seem to get the following type of screen (through nomachine remote desktop client):

*Sorry... I am unable to post my screenshot here because I do not have the 10 reputation points in askubuntu yet.... darn it...*

*But the screen has a terminal at the top left of the screen (not an actual "window"), and the ubuntu loading screen is still behind it.*

I've tried running `startx` as you can see. But, this seems to actually be x server. But if I run `unity --reset`, it seems that a lot of the desktop gets restored, but... with a lot of errors and warnings and the next time I boot, it's the same story all over again. Also, when I close the terminal window after getting my desktop back, I get thrown back at the login screen.

Please bear with my lack of knowledge of ubuntu and it's underlying unix. I thank you in advance.

**Edit:** I've just tried disabling the autologin and check if logging in with another user would make a difference. First, I get the login screen as expected. Then I login as a different user then the autologin user (btw, if I try the autologin user from the login screen I get the same result as autologin). Then the screen only shows the background, nothing else, when trying right mouse click, I get the option menu to change background etc... Which I also can open. Nothing more, so no terminal at this user, but nothing else either.

**Edit 2:** I've managed to get the other user working again, by going to terminal (CTRL + ALT + T) executing CCSM. There I only had to check "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". When I did that, the desktop appeared.

So I do have a working user now (even after rebooting). But still, the other user still seems screwed. I tried the above there as well, I needed to enable a lot more of options there. ( as mentioned on: http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/04/missing-top-and-side-panels-in-unity.html) But still, no progress on this user...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Apparently, it was a lot easier then I thought. (like always) After enabling some settings in CCSM it still did not work for the one user. Apparently, in my ~/.dmrc, there was a line `session=xterm`. After changing that to `session=ubuntu`, I managed to fix the problem.